# Run Macro With Spaces Python 3.8

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, vba, pywin32

I have this code:

```
com_instance = Dispatch("Excel.Application") # USING WIN32COM
com_instance.Visible = True
com_instance.DisplayAlerts = False

(file_path, file_name) = os.path.split(script_file)
objworkbook = com_instance.Workbooks.Open(script_file)
xlmodule = objworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString(strcode.strip())
aux = "'"+ file_name + "'" + '!Module1.ExTracking'
com_instance.Application.Run(aux)
objworkbook.SaveAs(os.path.join(conv_scripts_dir, file_name))
com_instance.Quit()
```

But I get this error:

```
result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Cannot run the macro "\'Tracking NS 29Ene20.xlsx\'!Module1.ExTracking". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.", u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

I dont know why Python add those "\" in the file name, maybe is because of this.

Please Help me. Thanks

Comment: Can you run a macro which already exists in the file?

Comment: Are you sure your file extension is `.xlsx`? If so, how can you have a Module inside it?

Comment: I can run this code on a pc with python 3.5.2 , but when i run it on a pc with python 3.8 i got the error. ( I can't install python 3.5.2 becuase its a pc from my work, so i installed python 3.8 from windows store). Please help me